# Getting JSON encoded variables from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i have this php code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id");
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $dataArray['var1'] = $item['var1'];
    $dataArray['var2'] = $item['var2'];
    $dataArray['var3'] = $item['var3'];
    array_push($return_arr,$dataArray);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

it's in my `ajax.php` file

Then I'm using jquery to send there id via ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'id='+id,
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    }
 });
```

and it alerts me this: `[{"var1":"somevarhere","var2":"somevarhere2","var3":"somevarhere3"}]`

can someone tell me please how I can access for ex. `var3` to get `somevarhere3`?

thanks

Comment: So your question is how to transform that json encoded string to an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Thanks to `Pascal MARTIN` I got the idea to parse the result so I used this:

```
data = data.substring(1,data.length-1);
data = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(data.var3);
```

first line removes [],
second line parses JSON to Object,
and third line accesses the property

Comment: Well, if your SQL query always return one, and only one, result, you'd better return a single object from PHP, and not an array that contains one object -- which is why those `[]` are there : your PHP code returns a JSON-encoded array.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of [**`jQuery.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the data it receives as first parameter is interpreted depending on the value of the **`dataType`** option passed to `jQuery.Ajax`.

What if you pass `'json'` for that parameter ?

Like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: 'id='+id,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    }
 });
```

Doing this, `jQuery.ajax` should interpret the data returned from the server as JSON.

Else, the documentation says that, if no dataType is specified *(quoting)* :

> jQuery will try to infer it based on
>   the MIME type of the response

So, the other solution would be to return some JSON content-type from the PHP code *(see [The right JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type))*, with something like this :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Before doing the echoing.

And, again, `jQuery.ajax` should interpret the data returned from the server as JSON.

Comment: I have added `dataType: 'json',` - this looks almost great, now it says that `data` is Object but when I `alert(data.toSource())` it still returns `[{"var1":"somevarhere","var2":"somevarhere2","var3":"somevarhere3"}]` and therefore it doesnt work. It think that it's because of those brackets ([])

Comment: well, now that your data is interpreted as JSON, you can access it like any other Javascript array that would contain one object ; for example : `data[0].var3`

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to access it like this:

```
data[0].var3
```

Where 0 is the index of the item in the array you want to access.